# vlookup returned #N/A

Tags: excel, vlookup

I want to `vlookup` the postal area name using `Postcode` for table below:

```
    Year    Postcode  Value 
 0  2015    886       500 
 1  2015    2170      25 
 2  2015    3056      2.5 
 3  2015    3057      0
```

I tried:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2, Sheet1!A2:F18276, 3, FALSE)
```

Table containing postal area name:

```
ID      Postcode    Locality                        State   Long        Lat DC 
230     0200        ANU                             ACT     149.119     -35.2777     ... (more columns)
218     0200        Australian National University  ACT     149.1189    -35.2777     ...
232     0800        DARWIN                          NT      130.83668   -12.458684   ...
233     0801        DARWIN                          NT      130.83668   -12.458684   ...
```

and it returned `#N/A`.

It worked on a hand-typed small sample but not didn't work in the real tables. I also tried changing data type from `text` to `general` but nothing changed.

---

Update:

I found out that it was caused by the data type: although I changed the type to `text` it seems it's not. I have to convert to `text` manually by adding `'` in front of the postcode. So the new question is: how do I convert entire column to `text`?

Comment: You likely want to make sure your table range is referenced absolutely, e.g. `$A$2:$F$18276`...  Also in your top table, is the `0`, `1`, `2`, ... the rows, or column A? If it's the rows, don't you want to look up `B2`, not `C2`?

Comment: Hi @BruceWayne thanks for the suggestion. I converted the table to absolute range; and for the column position, I retyped the formula selecting each column I need from the table so the column names are automatically filled and the results are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you show it shows a postcode as 886 (no leading zero), whereas in the lower table it shows leading zeroes.  Most likely this means that you have numbers in one place and strings in the other and the comparison is failing.

If you can edit the lower table, try this:

- Type a zero into a spare cell
- Select and copy the cell (CTRL-C)
- Select the "postcode" column in the lower table and do paste special -> add.  This should convert the strings to numbers if possible.

If you can't edit the lower table, change C2 from `886` to `'0886` and see if that tries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Daniel, I couldn't get your first method to work - I'm not sure if I didn't what you meant; for the second method, I couldn't add `0` in front of the postcode as the data format is `General`, I changed it to `text` (also the lookup table postcode column) to allow the `0` to be added but nothing happens

Comment: The format doesn't change what's in the cells, just how they're displayed, so it shouldn't affect anything here.  What do you mean when you say "nothing happens?"  You're unable to add the zero at the front?  Or you are and the lookup still fails?

Comment: Yeah I think I could add 0 after converting the data type to `text` but the lookup still failed.

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say you converted the data type to text.  I suspect what you actually did was to change the _format_ to text, which is a superficial change that doesn't actually change the underlying values.  Also, here you say that the lookup doesn't work, whereas above in the question edit you say it works now.  What is the situation?

Answer (score 1):

Create new postcode column using:

```
=TEXT(postcode_col , "0000")
```

Use this as `lookup_value` in the `VLOOKUP` formula.

Also, make sure in querying table, postcode column is on the leftmost.